# Related to Microsoft office 2010 software installation

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I have downloaded microsoft offfice 2010 from the net a trial version.

But a double click on the downloaded file brings up Nero window. For the installation I have uninstalled the nero but it again open the window of disk burning. Is the `.exe` file corrupt or there is some another method to download and install the microsoft office 2010?

Comment: Did you restart the computer after you uninstalled Nero? 

Maybe you should proofread what you have written. Some people that could be helpful might not answer this just because you didn't time out to proof read you question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the .exe file corrupt

You haven't downloaded the `.exe` - you have downloaded the Disc image as an ISO file [Install Magic Disc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm), mount the downloaded ISO file & proceed with installation